# I have a problem trying to install files with .tar.gz

Tags: tar

I tried to install .tar.gz files in my computer through command line with the

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz
```

and it gives me this error

```
tar (child): archive.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

anyone please help....

Comment: 1st thing: please confirm with `ls` that the file actually is where you attempt to extract it. "No such file or directory" states it is none existing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to view the contents of the file ? Since this file ends up with extension .gz. you can try unzipping (gunzip) it first.

To view the contents of the file

```
gunzip -l archive.tar.gz
```

Now try to unzip the file as well

```
gunzip archive.tar.gz
```

Above command should give you a "TAR ARCHIVE" in a result. See if it extracts the tar archive and now you can try extracting the tar package.

```
tar -xvf archive.tar
```

"v" flag will verbosely print the output and will show the error message during archive process, if there is one.

Good Luck.